# "sed" or "awk" launched on opening terminal window

Tags: terminal, bash, startup, script

At some point, I've noticed strange behavior of Terminal app - now on opening new window i get this as normal:

```
Last login: Tue Nov 27 11:54:21 on ttys001
```

but can't see the "~" sign afterwards and window title shows "Terminal - sed - 80x24" which means that sed is running. After hitting two times "enter" key, everything goes normal, but now after every new command i enter, i have to hit twice "enter" after it. This drives me insane!
Have no idea what happened. Maybe there is some startup-configuration script for terminal/bash? I've checked .bash_profile it looks fine as it used to be.

Here is my .bash_profile file:

```
export DOCUMENTS=~/Documents
alias twrangler="open -a TextWrangler"
alias countloc="find -f . '(' -name '*.m' -or -name '*.mm' ')' -print | xargs wc -l"

# Terminal colours (after installing GNU coreutils)
# NM="\[\033[0;38m\]" #means no background and white lines
# HI="\[\033[0;37m\]" #change this for letter colors
# HII="\[\033[0;31m\]" #change this for letter colors
# SI="\[\033[0;33m\]" #this is for the current directory
# IN="\[\033[0m\]"
# export PS1="$NM[$SI\w$NM] $IN"

export HISTCONTROL=ignoredups # Ignores dupes in the history
shopt -s checkwinsize # After each command, checks the windows size and changes lines and columns

# bash completion settings (actually, these are readline settings)
bind "set completion-ignore-case on" # note: bind is used instead of setting these in .inputrc. This ignores case in bash completion
bind "set bell-style none" # No bell, because it's damn annoying
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous On" # this allows you to automatically show completion without double tab-ing

# Turn on advanced bash completion if the file exists (get it here: http://www.caliban.org/bash/index.shtml#completion)
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /etc/bash_completion
fi

# Useful aliases
alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS -hF'
alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lhF'
alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lAhF'

alias g='grep -i' #case insensitive grep
alias f='find . -iname'
alias ducks='du -cks * | sort -rn|head -11' # Lists the size of all the folders and files
alias top='top -o cpu'
alias systail='tail -f /var/log/system.log'

alias cd..="cd .."
alias c="clear"
alias e="exit"
alias ssh="ssh -X"
alias ..="cd .."
#alias mysqlstart='sudo /opt/local/bin/mysqld_safe5 &'
#alias mysqlstop='/opt/local/bin/mysqladmin5 -u root -p shutdown'
#alias remount='sudo ~/scripts/remount.rb'
#alias ffman='/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -ProfileManager'
#alias ffdev='/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P rainbow' #' -chrome chrome://chromebug/content/chromebug.xul -firefox'
#alias fft1='/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P test1'
#alias ffxr='/Applications/Minefield.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P xrefresh-dev' #' -chrome chrome://chromebug/content/chromebug.xul -firefox'
#alias ffxr2='/Applications/Minefield.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P xr2' #' -chrome chrome://chromebug/content/chromebug.xul -firefox'
#alias ff13='/Applications/Minefield.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P fb13' #' -chrome chrome://chromebug/content/chromebug.xul -firefox'
#alias ffhed='/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P hed' #' -chrome chrome://chromebug/content/chromebug.xul -firefox'
#alias ffgae='/Applications/Minefield.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P gae' #' -chrome chrome://chromebug/content/chromebug.xul -firefox'
#alias ffgae2='/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox -P gae' #' -chrome chrome://chromebug/content/chromebug.xul -firefox'
#alias runsvn='/usr/bin/sudo -u www /opt/local/bin/svnserve -d -r /var/svn'

#alias spotbuild='sudo mdutil -E /'

if [ -f /opt/local/etc/bash_completion ]; then
. /opt/local/etc/bash_completion
fi

COLOR_YELLOW="\[\e[33;10m\]"
COLOR_RED="\[\e[31;10m\]"
COLOR_GREEN="\[\e[32;10m\]"
COLOR_BLUE="\[\e[34;10m\]"
COLOR_NONE="\[\e[0m\]"
COLOR_NONEP="\[\e[38;0m\]"

git_dirty_flag() {
git status 2> /dev/null | grep -c : | awk '{if ($1 > 0) print "‚ö°"}'
}

parse_git_branch() {
git branch --no-color 2> /dev/null | sed -e '/^[^*]/d' -e 's/* \(.*\)/ \1/'
}

prompt_func() {
previous_return_value=$?;
prompt="${COLOR_BLUE}\w${COLOR_GREEN}$(parse_git_branch)${COLOR_YELLOW}$(git_dirty_flag)${COLOR_NONEP}"
if test $previous_return_value -eq 0
then
PS1="${prompt}${COLOR_NONEP}${COLOR_NONE} "
else
PS1="${prompt}${COLOR_RED}${COLOR_NONE} "
fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=prompt_func

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2011-11-02_at_22:46:11: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of your startup scripts? Are there any other in your home dir?

Comment: well, just .bash_profile that i used for ages. it sets up paths, some environmental variables and aliases. its quite big to post here. do you think it could be the issue?

Comment: ok, maybe you're right. i removed .bash_profile at all and everything works now. hm, the rest is to figure out what caused that behaviour

Answer (score 1):

ok, I've found the problem. it was tricky and several different results led to it. but it always wise to figure out our mistakes, so here was mine:

1. i used **.bash_profile** file with some settings for convenient use (like aliases, coloring, etc.). i just copied that file from my friend and never looked at it thoroughly, however should done this. there are some bash functions which adds to the variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` the name of current git branch, so it is convenient when you make `cd` in this folder, the branch is shown automatically in green color near `~` sign, like this: "`~master`". you can find this in .bash_profile as `prompt_func` and `parse_git_branch` functions. they are using `git` command
2. this profile file always worked well. but at some point (today) it stopped. so i just pulled my bash history and after some thorough exploration and thinking have found the problem.
   here is the excerpt of output from `history`:

> 437  curl -s -O http://github-media-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/osx/git-credential-osxkeychain
>   438  chmod u+x git-credential-osxkeychain
>   439  sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain `which git`

strange command

```
sudo mv git-credential-osxkeychain `which git`
```

was intended to move file **git-credential-osxkeychain** to the directory, where git resides (`which git`), for my system it is **/usr/bin/git**. but what actually was made is that this file was moved to the  directory **/usr/bin** with the name **git** and the directory with the git itself was just overwritten by that file, e.d. gone!!
so now, coming back to the scripts functions in **.bash_profile** which is using git, everything looks simple and obvious - there is no git, but the file named git (which is executable btw - utility for setting up git credentials) and functions use this utility thinking that it is git itself.

therefore now, solution for me is to restore git installation and rename **git** file back to **git-credential-osxkeychain**

resume - **never write bash code in *one-line* unless you clearly understand what will bring each statement of it to the results**

thanks for all who took part in this.

Comment: `which ` returns the full part and not just the directory component I'm afraid.

Comment: that's true, didn't realize that before

Answer (score 0):

The only other scripts you are sourcing in your `.bash_profile` are

```
/etc/bash_completion
```

and

```
/opt/local/etc/bash_completion
```

I would check if they were recently updated and if they are damaged. In any case I would avoid calling both (which could also be the problem). If you use bash-completion from MacPorts just use the second.

Comment: i've checked it - the if statement not executed, because there is no such file in that directory. anyway, thanks for contribution! i've figured out the problem and posted it as an answer